# How to make blocks in spawn unbreakable in survival?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So on my multiplayer server on Minecraft Education Edition I can't seem to figure out how to make the blocks in spawn unbreakable. I know adventure mode fixes that but it's a survival world. I don't want them in adventure, so how do I make the blocks in spawn unbreakable?

Comment: Please only ask one question per question.

Comment: Sorry I'm new and I still cant figure out how to do this stuff. Please answer my question, looking on YT didn't really help

Comment: Also, if you're new here, I strongly recommend reading the [tour] and at least parts of the [help].

Comment: If you have multiple questions you are free to [Ask](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) more than one at a time. But please don't have them all on a single question post.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods in doing this

1. Unbreakable blocks

A list of unbreakible blocks in survival include bedrock, barrier blocks and command blocks

2. /clone command

Using a command block clone a duplicate of your spawn with a repeating command block

> NOTE: making edits to your spawn is only possible it the duplicate being cloned

3. Cobblestone generators

Using multiple cobblestone generators and pistons to replace fallen walls

4. Barrier blocks

Place a beautiful background and coat the inside with barrier blocks

> NOTE: to get command blocks and barriers can be done in chat with “/give (name) command_block OR barrier

Comment: The unbreakable block thing for me didn't really make any sense. Is there a way to spawn wolves when I get hit? and if you could answer the other questions I'd like that. or if you know how to put factions on a multiplayer server that be great. Its not like a server everyone can join its one where people in my wifi can join. minecraft education edition

Comment: Hey, Please post 1 question per post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in Education Edition, placing some Deny Blocks near the bottom of the world will prevent modification from players without the "World Builder" status

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Allow_and_Deny_Blocks